# Run .EXE in Node.JS

Tags: javascript, c++, node.js

I am having trouble running a external executable in Node.Js. 
My code looks like this:

```
function executeFile(m, cb) {
    var urlTarget = "D:/thesis_node/upload/1.jpeg";
    var urlScene = "D:/thesis_node/upload/scene.jpeg";
    exec(__execDirName+'/FeatureDetection.exe', [urlTarget, urlScene], function(error, stdout, stderr) {
        if(error) return cb(error);
        cb(null, stdout);
    });
}
```

When I run the script, it did nothing and it seems It's doing a process but it never ends. If I run my EXE file using Command Prompt, it works. The .exe file returns value. I need to get that value.

**Update**

Actually I started to think something might be wrong with my C++ code in returning the value.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
   int a = 5 + 10;
   return a; //Will this a can be received by Node.Js?
}
```

Is this the correct way to do that?

Comment: Can you check process manager and see if **FeatureDetection.exe** is still running?

Comment: I run it, and check my process manager directly but didn't find **FeatureDetection.exe** is running. Or it might be I did not notice since the process only takes about 1 second. @zero298

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe you provide the arguments you want to be provided to the child process as the second argument to `child_process.exec()`.  Instead you concatenate the arguments directly into the first argument of `exec()`.

See the documentation here: [`child_process.exec(command[, options][, callback])`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback)

Specifically:

> command <String> The command to run, with **space-separated arguments**

So for your case, you would want something like:

```
var cmdToExec = (__execDirName + '/FeatureDetection.exe' + ' ' + urlTarget + ' ' + urlScene);

exec(cmdToExec, function(){...});
```

---

Alternatively, you could try [`child_process.execFile(file[, args][, options][, callback])`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_execfile_file_args_options_callback)

**`execFile()`** as apposed to `exec()`, which you are using now, **does** take an arguments array as a second parameter.

Comment: So I tried using your snippet
`var cmdToExec = (__execDirName + '/FeatureDetection.exe' + ' ' + urlTarget + ' ' + urlScene);

exec(cmdToExec, function(){...});`

and it is still not working. It's looks like the node is responding to the exec call, but nothing is actually happening. And as for `execFile()` using my previous code should have been okay, right? @zero298